# Подскажите можно ли на питоне написать вот такой простой как для php код?

Tags: php, python

Доброго времени суток 
Подскажите можно ли на питоне написать вот такой простой как для php код?

```
    if(isset($_POST['longitude'])) {

    $lng = $_POST['longitude'];
}
```

Если можно подскажите как заранее огромное спасибо

Comment: Можно. Или пользуйте библиотеку каторая сделает это за вас, или парсите сам запрос.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP

Comment: Гуглил уже это толком ничего не нашел..только с использованием фреймворка джанго. Хочется как то легко сделать тоже самое что и на пхп(

Comment: В **PHP** всё не так легко как вы думаете. Он парсит для вас, но не для всех форматов(типов контента), так что если захотите получать `json` или данные через `PUT` запрос, то надо парсить самому. И **Python**, это язык общего назначения и не заточен для web изначально. т.е. Вам всё равно надо будет создать сервер обрабатывать запросы... Или готовая библиотека посмотрите flask(он поменьше)

Answer (score 1):

[StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python). Там собрали разные способы. Процитирую самый простой

```
import cgi

post = cgi.FieldStorage()
if "longitude" in post:
    lng = form["longitude"]
```

Также, ознакомьтесь с [документацией](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html).